# Group same Days by name of day from Datetime Format in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have column named `start` im my database where i store thousands of `dates` (not the ones you can eat) in the following format:

```
2019-05-04 07:30:00
```

To get some stats im using `google.charts` and trying to group the values by the name of days (Monday, Thuesday).

So far I have the following. Any idea how to extract the day name from the datetime and group them by the same names to get something like:

Monday 120

Thuesday 236

Wednesday 987

and so on

[image]

**Database Structure:**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.7deb1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4  COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Select Statement so far:**

```
$sql_8 = "SELECT `start` count(*) as number FROM test GROUP BY `start` ";
```

**PHP Query and Script part:**

```
<?php   
    $result_8 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_8); 
?> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
function drawTable() {
    
    
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
        data.addRows([ 
        
            <?php  
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_8)) { 
                    
                    $date = $row["start"];
                    echo "[ ' ".$date." ', ".$row["number"]." ],";   
                }
            ?>          
                  
        ]); 
                     
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div_8'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%',});
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your table schema

Comment: updated my question and added the "Database Structure"

Answer (score 0):

The MySql / MariaDB function [DAYOFWEEK(start)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) gives you a number 1-7 (1 == Sunday) for any DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP value. So if you `GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(start) ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(start)` you will get a useful result set in a useful order.

Something like this query will work.

```sql
SELECT DAYNAME(start) weekday,
       count(*) as number
  FROM test 
 GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(start)
 ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(start);
```

**Pro tip**: Every minute you spend studying your RDBMS's date and time arithmetic operations will save you hours in the future.

Comment: just tried - i have 7 rows now but the day column still showing a date like 2022-10-19 02:40:00 for each row

Comment: thx for the pro tip! The day column is empty now - nothing to see...

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to group by day name regardless of in what year or month the date is, then you can use MySQL [DAYNAME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(`Start`) AS Daynm,
       COUNT(*) AS number
  FROM test
GROUP BY Daynm;
```

And maybe if you want to order by day ascending, then add another function `WEEKDAY()` - `Monday` as it's first day; or `DAYOFWEEK()` - Sunday as it's first day.

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(`Start`) AS Wkday,
       DAYNAME(`Start`) AS Daynm,
       COUNT(*) AS number
  FROM test
GROUP BY Wkday, Daynm
  ORDER BY Wkday;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aFmLbljs)

Comment: it returns no day name. If i change the format in the while clause with `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_from_database)` and then to `day->format('l')` im able to show the day names. Just the sql statement dont work in may case. The count number shows up and seems ok.

Comment: So, does it mean that your column datatype is not exactly `DATETIME` and the data value is not exactly in the correct datetime format? Can you show what `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtablename;` returns?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dB2mJgd the structure and dates return as `2019-05-04 07:30:00` created the databse from my cpanel and using phpmyadmin

Comment: updated my question and added the "Database Structure"

Comment: The table datatype is correct so I would assume that the problem here is not the MySQL `DAYNAME()` function; you can try this by running the query using MySQL tool like Workbench or PHPmyadmin and see.